# Android Kotlin/ FirebaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent Error.. plz help me

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm doing Modulization for my kotlin study team that don't know firebase usage. when i try to call the function(named getEyeSavingData) then occur something problem...

location that calling function is A.kt

```
    isgTestButton.setOnClickListener {
                val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                val eDB = database.getReference("eyesaving")
    
                //eDB.child("food").child("test").setValue(EyeSavingData("name", "element", "effect", 1234, "explain"))
                setEyeSavingData(Category.food, "orange", EyeSavingData("orange", "Vitamin C", "good at Eye", 1000, "Orange is Orange"))
                //set Data has good work
    
    
                val dTestVal = getEyeSavingData(Category.food, "orange")
                if(dTestVal != null)
                    isgTestTextView.text = dTestVal.name + dTestVal.element //Error?
            }
```

Modulization.kt

```
data class EyeSavingData(
    var name: String?,
    var element: String?,
    var effect: String?,
    var cost: Int?,
    var explain: String?
)

enum class Category {
    food, tea
}

/*
 *  함수명 : getEyeSavingData (카테고리(food, tea 등), 카테고리 내 음식 이름)
 *  반환값 : EyeSavingData 또는 null
 *  설명 : name 파라미터를 넣지 않고 호출할 경우 카테고리 내 전체 데이터를 EyeSavingData class 형태로 반환하고,
 *         name 파라미터에 값을 넣을 경우 카테고리 내 해당 이름의 데이터를 EyeSavingData 형태로 반환합니다.
 *  Tips : getEyeSavingData 를 호출할 때 파라미터는 Category.food, Category.tea 등을 사용하면 편리합니다.
 *  사용예시 : getEyeSavingData(Category.food, "orange")   // food 카테고리 내 orange 음식의 데이터를 반환합니다.
 */
public fun getEyeSavingData(categoryEnum: Category, name: String) : EyeSavingData? {
    var category: String?
    when(categoryEnum){
        Category.food -> category = "food"
        Category.tea -> category = "tea"
    }
    var userData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("eyesaving")
    var retData: EyeSavingData? = null

    val eData = userData.child(category).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            var eDataString = p0.getValue() as Map<String, EyeSavingData?>
            retData = eDataString.get(name) //i assume happening error is here
        }
    })
    return retData
}

public fun setEyeSavingData(categoryEnum: Category, name: String, data: EyeSavingData){
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("eyesaving")
    var category: String?
    when(categoryEnum){
        Category.food -> category = "food"
        Category.tea -> category = "tea"
    }
    database.child(category).child(name).setValue(data)
}
```

Test View
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4srA.png)

Error Display
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4agwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getEyeSavingData` will always return `null` because `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is asynchronous.

So if you want to use data from this call you can get it inside `onDataChange` like this -

```
 val eData = userData.child(category).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            var eDataString = p0.getValue() as Map<String, EyeSavingData?>
            retData = eDataString.get(name) 
            //Here you can use retData
            if(dTestVal != null)
                isgTestTextView.text = dTestVal.name + dTestVal.element
        }
    })
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much TvT, I get to know that it is asynchronous. maybe I can resove it